# Networkx - Get probability p(k) from network

Tags: networkx, probability-distribution

I have plotted the histogram of `network` (dataframe), with count of 'k' node connections, like so:

```
import seaborn as sns

parameter ='k'
sns.histplot(network[parameter])
```

[image]

But now I need to create a modular random graph using above group distribution with:

```
from networkx.generators.community import random_partition_graph

random_partition_graph(sizes, p_in, p_out, seed=None, directed=False)
```

And, instead of counts, I need this value `p(k)`, which must be passed as `p_in`.

```
p_in (float)
probability of edges with in groups
```

---

How do I get `p(k)` from my `network`?

Comment: Does the random graph need to be a `random_partition_graph`? It looks like you could get the result you want by using one of the random graphs listed [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generators.html#module-networkx.generators.degree_seq).

Comment: I don't know. I have two networks, and I need to project connections from one into another, using some probabiity p. But what I need here actually is to infer the probability from my REAL graph distribution.

Comment: If you've got the number with degree `k`, then divide this by the population size and you've got the probability a random node has degree `k`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would handle what you described. First, you can normalize your histogram such that the integral of the histogram is equal to 1. This can be done by setting the `weights` argument of your histogram appropriately. This histogram can then be considered the probability distribution of your degrees. Now that you have this probability distribution, i.e. a list of probability (`deg_prob` in the code) you can randomly sample from it using `np.random.choice(np.arange(np.amin(degrees),np.amax(degrees)+1), p=deg_prob, size=N_sampling)`. From this random sampling, you can then create a random `expected_degree_graph` by just passing your samples in the `w` argument.
You can then compare the degree distribution of your original graph with the one from your random graph.

See below for the code and more details:

```py
import networkx as nx
from networkx.generators.random_graphs import binomial_graph
from networkx.generators.degree_seq import expected_degree_graph
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig=plt.figure()

N_nodes=1000
G=binomial_graph(n=N_nodes, p=0.01, seed=0) #Creating a random graph as data
degrees = np.array([G.degree(n) for n in G.nodes()])#Computing degrees of nodes
bins_val=np.arange(np.amin(degrees),np.amax(degrees)+2) #Bins

deg_prob,_,_=plt.hist(degrees,bins=bins_val,align='left',weights=np.ones_like(degrees)/N_nodes,
                      color='tab:orange',alpha=0.3,label='Original distribution')#Histogram

#Sampling from distribution
N_sampling=500
random_sampling=np.random.choice(np.arange(np.amin(degrees),np.amax(degrees)+1), p=deg_prob, size=N_sampling)

#Creating random graph from samples
G_random_sampling=expected_degree_graph(random_sampling,seed=0,selfloops=False)
degrees_random_sampling = np.array([G_random_sampling.degree(n) for n in G_random_sampling.nodes()])

deg_prob_random_sampling,_,_=plt.hist(degrees_random_sampling,bins=bins_val,align='left',
                                      weights=np.ones_like(degrees_random_sampling)/N_sampling,color='tab:blue',label='Sample distribution',alpha=0.3)

#Plotting both histograms
plt.xticks(bins_val)
plt.xlabel('degree')
plt.ylabel('Prob')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The output then gives:

[image]